# How do i add cumulative values from an array

Tags: javascript

```
let Tota_principal = h.map(value=> value['Principal'])

var new_array = [];
Tota_principal.reduce(function(a,b,i) { 
    return new_array[i] = a+b; 
},0)

console.log(new_array)
```

The new_array gives a concatenated value rather than a cumulative sum of the table. also where do i add toFixed()

Comment: please add some data as well.

Comment: Use `parseFloat(b)` instead of just `b`.

Comment: use `toFixed()` when you're displaying the results, not when you're calculating.

Comment: You're getting concatenation because the array contains strings rather than numbers. It would be better if you put numbers in the array in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar. The value is not coming from a source. i am only fetching the values.So how do i convert from string to an int

Comment: @Barmar. thanks i have been able to convert to int. but where do i use toFixed() in my return array

Comment: please add the missing parts to the question, if the problem is different from the duplicate target.

Comment: @EngrEbukaOrioha You don't. You use it when displaying the results. `console.log(toFixed(new_array[i], 2))`

Comment: @Barmar. thats the error 'toFixed is not defined'

Comment: Sorry, meant `console.log(new_array[i].toFixed(2))`

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks. this explains what i needed 'toFixed() when you're displaying the results, not when you're calculating'